# Getting error while validating names and names in email column

Tags: r

I am trying to make it dynamic so that it will detect separator dynamically by user provided separator

```
df <-  data.frame(name= c("ali, wing sam","nick, jone","mak, liam","r, mush","sink, dude"),
                  Email = c("sam.wing.ali1@xyz.com","nick.jone @xyz.com","liam.mak@xyz.com","r.mush@xyz.com","dude.sink@xyz.com"))

separator = ", "

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(name,Email), tolower), 
         email_name1 = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)'),
         email_name = str_extract(Email, '.*?(?=@)')) %>%
  separate(col = email_name, into = c('f','s','l'), sep = '\\.', fill = 'right') %>%
  mutate(l = replace_na(l,''), 
         email_name_rev = str_squish(str_c(l,s,f, sep = "."))) %>%
  mutate(match1 = +(name == email_name_rev | name == email_name1)) %>%
  select(-c(f,s,l))
```

what i am doing wrong in my code.....??

now I am getting the output be like below

Comment: Is there something different to your recently deleted question [compare names in email and names column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65183048/10488504) ?

Comment: actually i want to know what i am doing wrong in my code, i want to update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
library(tidyverse)


separator = ", "

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(name,Email), tolower), 
         email_name1 = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)'),
         email_name1 = str_replace_all(email_name1, "[.@]", separator),
         email_name = str_extract(Email, '.*?(?=@)')) %>%
  separate(col = email_name, into = c('f','s','l'), sep = '\\.', fill = 'right') %>%
  mutate(l = replace_na(l,''), 
         email_name_rev = trimws(str_c(l,s,f, sep = separator), whitespace = separator)) %>%
  mutate(match1 = +(name == email_name_rev | name == email_name1)) %>%
  select(-c(f,s,l))


#           name                 Email     email_name1  email_name_rev match1
#1 ali, wing sam sam.wing.ali1@xyz.com sam, wing, ali1 ali1, wing, sam      0
#2    nick, jone    nick.jone @xyz.com     nick, jone      jone , nick      0
#3     mak, liam      liam.mak@xyz.com       liam, mak       mak, liam      1
#4       r, mush        r.mush@xyz.com         r, mush         mush, r      1
#5    sink, dude     dude.sink@xyz.com      dude, sink      sink, dude      1
```

- No need to write separate `mutate` for each line.
- Add `fill = 'right'` in `separate` to avoid getting the warning.
- You have double at (`'@@'`) in first email not sure if it is how your real data is or this is just a typo. I have included the code to remove it.

Comment: so sometimes the separator can be space or comma like below but i am getting "."  in email_name_rev column like for instance

Comment: df <-  data.frame(name= c("ali, wing sam","nick, jone","mak, liam","r, mush","sink, dude"),
                  Email = c("sam.wing.ali1@xyz.com","nick.jone @xyz.com","liam.mak@xyz.com","r.mush@xyz.com","dude.sink@xyz.com"))

separator = ", "

Comment: i am doing this way
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(name,Email), tolower), 
         email_name1 = str_extract(Email, '.*(?=@)'),
         email_name1 = str_replace_all(email_name1, "[.@]", "."),
         email_name = str_extract(Email, '.*?(?=@)')) %>%
  separate(col = email_name, into = c('f','s','l'), sep = '\\.', fill = 'right') %>%
  mutate(l = replace_na(l,''), 
         email_name_rev = str_squish(str_c(l,s,f, sep = "."))) %>%
  mutate(match1 = +(name == email_name_rev | name == email_name1)) %>%
  select(-c(f,s,l))

Comment: You have double at ('@@') in first email not sure if it is how your real data is or this is just a typo. I have included the code to remove it.

Yes email column can have typos sometimes, Thanks

Comment: It is difficult to read code in comments. It would be better if you could update your post with additional queries. Can you try the updated answer I added `trimws` with `whitespace = separator`

Comment: I have updated the code  in question. but if separator i change with ", " then i am getting "." before names in column email_name_rev  in output .

how i  can resolve it.

Comment: @newcomer Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: i have checked but the second should give true and giving false and also there is extra space getting in email_name_rev column

Comment: i mean how i can remove extra spaces from start of the string and end of the string from mutated columns

Comment: You can use `trimws` to remove extra spaces. `mutate(across(c(col1, col2), trimws))`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `name` and use `grepl` to test if all the subnames are in the `Email`.

```
mapply(function(x, y) all(sapply(paste0("\\b",x,"\\b"), grepl, y)),
 strsplit(df$name, " "), df$Email)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And for `gsub` and `rev` and `strsplit` for the mail names:

```
(x <- gsub(".", " ", sub("@.*", "", df$Email), fixed = TRUE))
#[1] "sam wing ali" "nick jone"    "liam mak1"    "r mush"       "dude sink"   

sapply(strsplit(x, " ", TRUE), function(y) paste(rev(y), collapse = " "))
#[1] "ali wing sam" "jone nick"    "mak1 liam"    "mush r"       "sink dude"
```